# expect(panel).toBeInTheDocument() throws error on test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

Reactjs with typescript, while do the testing to expect `toBeInTheDocument` throws the error. not able to understand.

I have multiple tabs, while the page loads, only the `initialTab` will be visible. rest of them should be hidden. that's what I am doing the test. But `not.toBeInTheDocument` works. but `toBeInTheDocument` not working. any one help me to understand?

here is the original panel tsx:

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { useTabsContext } from './Tabs';

type TabPanelProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  id: string;
};

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { id, children } = props;
  const activeTab = useTabsContext();
  return (
    <div
      id={`tab-panel-${id}`}
      role='tabpanel'
      aria-labelledby={`tab-${id}`}
      hidden={id !== activeTab}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TabPanel;
```

here is my test, includes the `TablePanel`:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from 'test-utils';
import Tab from './Tab';
import TabPanel from './TabPanel';
import Tabs from './Tabs';

const renderTabs = () =>
  render(
    <Tabs initialActiveTab='account'>
      <div className='flex mb-5'>
        <Tab id='account'>Account</Tab>
        <Tab id='settings'>Settings</Tab>
      </div>
      <div className='flex p-4 border'>
        <TabPanel data-testid='account' id='account'>
          Account Panel
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel data-testid='settings' id='settings'>
          Settings Panel
        </TabPanel>
      </div>
    </Tabs>
  );

describe('Tabs.tsx', () => {
  it('Tabs items have correct text', async () => {
    renderTabs();
    screen.getByText('Account');
    screen.getByText('Account Panel');
  });
  it('Settings Tab item is hidden at the start', async () => {
    renderTabs();
    await waitFor(() => {
      const panel = screen.queryByTestId('settings');
      expect(panel).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
  it('Account Tab item is visible at the start', async () => {
    renderTabs();
    await waitFor(() => {
      const panel = screen.queryByTestId('account');
      expect(panel).toBeInTheDocument(); //error
    });
  });
});
```

error getting as :

```
Error: expect(received).toBeInTheDocument()

received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
```

what is the cause here? please help to resolve this issue.

my tabs component:

```
import { contextFactory } from '@/context/helpers/contextFactory';
    import { Dispatch, ReactNode, SetStateAction, useState } from 'react';
    
    export type ActiveTab = string;
    export type SetActiveTab = Dispatch<SetStateAction<ActiveTab>>;
    
    const [useTabsContext, TabsContext] = contextFactory<ActiveTab>();
    const [useTabsActionsContext, TabsActionsContext] =
      contextFactory<SetActiveTab>();
    
    export { useTabsContext, useTabsActionsContext };
    
    type TabsProps = {
      children: ReactNode;
      initialActiveTab: string;
    };
    
    function Tabs(props: TabsProps) {
      const { children, initialActiveTab } = props;
      const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(initialActiveTab);
    
      return (
        <TabsContext.Provider value={activeTab}>
          <TabsActionsContext.Provider value={setActiveTab}>
            {children}
          </TabsActionsContext.Provider>
        </TabsContext.Provider>
      );
    }
    export default Tabs;
```

**UPDATE**
my App component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Tabs initialActiveTab='account'>
        <div className='flex mb-5'>
          <Tab id='account'>Account</Tab>
          <Tab id='settings'>Settings</Tab>
          <Tab id='privacy'>Privacy</Tab>
        </div>
        <div className='flex p-4 border'>
          <TabPanel id='account' data-testid='account'>
            Account Panel
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel id='settings' data-testid='settings'>
            Settings Panel
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel id='privacy' data-testid='privacy'>
            Privacy Panel
          </TabPanel>
        </div>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's all about the implementation of the `Tabs` component. Show the minimal, complete code

Comment: @LinDu - added the `Tabs` component. can you check? I did not implement the `Provider`. is it required? please help me

Comment: That's because there isn't any element **in the DOM** with `data-testid="account"`. You should set that attribute for the `div` in `TabPanel`. Anyway, to use `id` and `data-testid` to find elements you're missing an opportunity to test for accessibility

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - it is there already. can you please check `App` component?

Comment: It's not. You're adding `data-testid` as a property of `TabPanel` but it does not make it to the DOM. When you render `TabPanel` you just add the `id` attribute and that's all. `screen.queryByTestId()` searches the DOM, not the React tree.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - I agree. I got it. let me try. thanks for your advice

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti; it works. can you add your suggestion as answer to accept?